# Finding default value of columns of all tables in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Is it possible to write any such query to get default value of all columns in the tables in MS access 2010?

Answer (score 4):

The info you want is available via VBA.

```
CurrentDb.TableDefs({table name}).Fields({field name}).DefaultValue
```

This function will find all of them in the DB.

```
Sub Default()
    Dim TD As TableDef
    Dim Fld As Field
    For Each TD In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If TD.Attributes = 0 Then
            For Each Fld In TD.Fields
                Debug.Print TD.Name & " :: " & Fld.Name & " :: " & Fld.DefaultValue
            Next Fld
        End If
    Next TD
End Sub
```

Comment: Tom Collins suggestion worked for me (accdb) after commenting two Dim lines.

Comment: To run this code as is, add a reference to Microsoft DAO.  Or just comment out the two Dim lines as @WiSeeker says.